# splitting a list into two lists based on odd/even indices

Tags: r, list

I have a list of the form:

```
dat[[1]], dat[[2]], ..., dat[[n]]
```

and I would like to obtain instead two separate lists, one containing dat with odd indices and the other one with even indices, i.e.:

```
new_dat_odd <- dat[[1]], dat[[3]], dat[[5]], ...
new_dat_even <- dat[[2]], dat[[4]], dat[[6]], ...
```

In trying to do this, my main issue is I can't find how to refer to the indices of a list in R.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**1)** If `L` is the list then we can use this code where we note that `1:2` is recycled as needed:

```
s <- split(L, 1:2)
```

**1a)** The above works whether the list is even or odd length but as per the comment if odd it gives a warning.  The followingi modification gives the same answer but gives no warning:

```
s <- split(L, rep(1:2, length = length(L)))
```

In either of the above `s[[1]]` and `s[[2]]` are the two lists.  For example,

```
> L <- as.list(1:10)
> str(split(L, 1:2))
List of 2
 $ 1:List of 5
  ..$ : int 1
  ..$ : int 3
  ..$ : int 5
  ..$ : int 7
  ..$ : int 9
 $ 2:List of 5
  ..$ : int 2
  ..$ : int 4
  ..$ : int 6
  ..$ : int 8
  ..$ : int 10
```

**2)** Here is another way:

```
is.odd <- rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), length = length(L))
list(odd = L[is.odd], even = L[!is.odd])
```

**Update** Added 1a and 2.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could build a sequence using `seq` and subset the original data with that sequence:

```
lst <- list(1:3, 2:4, 3:5)
lst
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3

#[[2]]
#[1] 2 3 4

#[[3]]
#[1] 3 4 5

lst_even <- lst[seq(2,length(lst),2)]
lst_odd <- lst[seq(1,length(lst),2)]


lst_odd
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3

#[[2]]
#[1] 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 1):

I have at times found it easier to work with lists by coercing them to data frames and using a modern `dplyr` solution, so here is an extra option. Notice that this is a data frame, so if you have a list to work with, first create a data frame using `data.frame(yourlistname)`. Here is some sample data.

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

structure(list(z = c(0.334237399835172, 0.468852147809068, 0.317526015236499, 
0.487024179746106, 0.303294768702877, 0.502790849577665)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("lower1", "upper1", "lower2", "upper2", "lower3", "upper3"))
```

Using the modulo command `%%` you can divide row numbers by 2 to identify odd and even rows.

```
> df %>% mutate(modulo=row_number() %% 2)
          z modulo
1 0.3342374      1
2 0.4688521      0
3 0.3175260      1
4 0.4870242      0
5 0.3032948      1
6 0.5027908      0
```

Now you can pick the even rows:

```
> df %>% slice(which(row_number() %% 2 == 1))
          z
1 0.3342374
2 0.3175260
3 0.3032948
```

Or pick the odd rows:

```
> df %>% slice(which(row_number() %% 2 == 0))
          z
1 0.4688521
2 0.4870242
3 0.5027908
```

Or get a vector directly by adding some more information to the pipes:

```
> df %>% slice(which(row_number() %% 2 == 1)) %>% unname() %>% unlist() -> your.data

> your.data
[1] 0.3342374 0.3175260 0.3032948

> typeof(your.data)
[1] "double"
```